# Mapbox.js 2.1.4: Safari/Firefox error loading @2x tiles

Tags: mapbox

in the following website: [www.varandaproducts.com](http://www.varandaproducts.com) I get to automatically load @2x tiles in Chrome but not in Safari desktop and mobile.

I'm using the following code to load mapbox.js:

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.4/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.4/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

And to call the map:

```
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidmFyYW5kYXByb2R1Y3RzIiwiYSI6Imt1QVkxOFkifQ.Sq5XxiJ93KHX1q-RorqP_g';
var caixaComeco = L.latLng(-50, 180),
    caixaFim = L.latLng(50, -180),
    caixa = L.latLngBounds(caixaComeco, caixaFim);

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'varandaproducts.k563jneh', {
    maxBounds: caixa,
});
</script>
```

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

No luck with Mapbox's support or with opening an issue on Github.

I wonder if there's anything on the .js that parses the image address in a wrong way.

When I inspect the code and the errors, I get a 404 for many tiles on safari, whereas the same tiles load successfully on Chrome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at your source, it appears you're using v1.6.3 of Mapbox?

Comment: Hi @BrettDeWoody , thanks for answering. Yes I have just switched back, but you can see it working with 2.1.4 here:

http://www.varandaproducts.com/index-214.html

Comment: Are you serving these images from your own server?

Comment: No, from mapbox's server. Got a basic plan. It's really strange that I get a 404 for most images on Firefox/Safari and not on Chrome. Same filenames and locations! :S